# Inject chrome browser extension content script based on URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to have my background page watch the URL and call chrome.tabs.executeScript on certain URLs.  What API should I call to watch the URL in such a manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) can be used to detect [tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab) loads. This will not detect navigation within frames though:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
   if (info.status === 'complete' && /some_reg_ex_pattern/.test(tab.url)) {
       // ...
   }
});
```

For this purpose, you'd better use a content script, with [`all_frames` set to true](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration). Within the content script, you can inject code using the methods as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089). Then use the page's `location` object to filter URLs.