# Chrome Extension - Autorun

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, autorun

I am wondering if it is possible to automatically run my extension (or a function in my extension) each time a page loads? Right now, I have it set that you would click the icon Browser Action icon to run my extension.

Comment: See also: [Chrome Extension - Auto Run a Function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9916089/938089?chrome-extension-auto-run-a-function)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've got two options:

1. Inject code as a [Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html), using the matching rules as defined in the [manifest file](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration).
2. A [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html), using the [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) event. Use the [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) method to inject script.

See also:

1. [Building a Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension)
2. [Inject chrome browser extension content script based on URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880773/inject-chrome-browser-extension-content-script-based-on-url)