# Load remote webpage in background page: Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to load a remote webpage into a background page using a chrome extension?

```
"background": {
    "page": "local.html"
  }
```

works, but

```
"background": {
    "page": "http://...."
  }
```

fails with the following error:

```
Could not load background page http://....
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<s>No, that's not possible.</s> It is **possible** since Chrome 22 - see the bottom of the answer.

You *can* [whitelist a `https:` resource in the manifest file](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H2-3) file, so that your background script can manually be constructed. Make sure that you include a fallback resource in your extension, in the case that the network is down:

```
<!-- ... doctype etc ... (background.html) -->
<script src="https://..../external_bg.js"></script>
<script src="bg.js"></script>
```

Because of the [Content security policy (CSP)](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html), you cannot run inline JavaScript, so you *have to* use external JS files. `bg.js` may look like:

```
if (!window.namespace_of_external_bg) {
    // Fallback, by defining fallback methods or injecting a new script:
    document.write('<script src="fallback_bg.js"></script>');
}
```

If you want to dynamically construct a page, avoid use of `eval`-like methods, because these are also forbidden by the CSP. You can write a template, and request external values to populate your template. `localStorage` can be used to cache variables. For an example on caching external resources, see [Chrome extension adding external javascript to current page's html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371025/938089). This answer referred to **Content scripts**, so the exact method cannot be used to enable caching scripts (because you would need to use `eval` to load the script). However, the caching technique can still be used.

---

I have also tried to use the following method, which does **not work** (included in this answer, so that you don't have to try it yourself):
Create a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob/) from the AJAX response, then use [`webkitURL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) to create a temporary URL to load the resource.

```
// Modification of https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371025
// Instead of `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, use 
// x.responseText  or  x.response (eg when using x.responseType='arraybuffer')
var blob = new Blob([x.responseText], {type: 'application/javascript'});
var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = url;
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

The previous code yields the following error:

> Refused to load the script 'blob:chrome-extension%3A//damgmplfpicjkeogacmlgiceidmilllf/96356d24-3680-4188-812e-5661d23e81df' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

### Loading external resources in the background page

Since Chrome 22, it is technically possible (using the `unsafe-eval` CSP policy) to load non-https resources in the background page. This obviously **not recommended** because of security concerns (because it's susceptible to the [MITM attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), for instance).

Here's an example to load an arbitrary resource and run it in the context of the background script.

```
function loadScript(url) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.onload = function() {
        eval(x.responseText); // <---- !!!
    };
    x.open('GET', url);
    x.send();
}
// Usage:
loadScript('http://badpractic.es/insecure.js');
```

- The **`unsafe-eval`** CSP policy must be specified.
- As usual, to make cross-origin requests, the URL must be whitelisted in the manifest at the `permissions` section, or the server must enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control).

So, the manifest should at least contain:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": ["http://badpractic.es/insecure.js"],
"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"] }
```

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed answer. Another approach I tried was to embed an iframe of the external website in `local.html`. It loads up, but I am left with no way to call javascript functions within the iframe, due to same-origin policy. I will give your solution a whirl.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon If you have control over the external page, then implement [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) (`reference_to_frame.contentWindow.postMessage`) to communicate with the frame.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the external page.

Comment: @Cthulhu Technologies have evolved, and have I updated my answer.

Comment: Very cool. I ended up redesigning my solution. I don't think this should be preferred though.

Comment: Thank you!  This was perfect!  I was stuck using a non-HTTP js; fortunately it's only accessible inside our work LAN.