# Chrome Extension: Manifest and remote google api (jquery)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extensions, and some of the functions that I'm going to have will make use of jQuery. I've had trouble finding a working solution online.

core.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
init();
});

function init()
{
    $(":button").click(function(){
        console.log("test");
        //more code here...
    });
}
```

extension.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>awesome</title>
<script src="scripts/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="getThem">GET!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

In my manifest I have the name, version, manifest_version (2), description, browser_action->default_popup (extention.html) and I'm not sure what to put for the rest. Can you help me piece together these basic elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page in the Chrome extension process cannot load external scripts, because of the [Content Security policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html). If you [inspect the popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup), the console would have revealed this error.

**The best solution is to bundle (jQuery) library with your extension - this has no additional cost, and makes your popup load faster.**

If you *really* want to embed scripts from an external URL, [relax the Content Security policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-remote-script), e.g..

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
```

This can only be done for the https scheme. If you want to load from a http resource, you're out of luck (there is actually [a work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11846136), but please don't use it.).

Comment: PS. Here's a screencast that shows how to identify and solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601615/the-chrome-extension-popup-is-not-working-click-events-are-not-handled/17612988#17612988