# Multiple JS files in Chrome Extension - how to load them?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I've wrote a Chrome Extension. My background.js file is quite large, so I want to split it to smaller parts and load specified methods when required (some kind of lazy-loading).

I've done this with Firefox:

```
// ( call for load specified lib )
var libPath = redExt.basePath + 'content/redExt/lib/' + redExt.browser + '/' + libName + '.js';
var service = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);
service.loadSubScript("chrome://" + libPath);
// ( executing loaded file )
```

Is there any possiblity to do it similar way in Webkit-based browsers? I've found solutions for how to inject multiple JS files into matching pages (using `manifest.json`) but cannot find way to include JS file just for extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found possible solution. Theres a simple implementation of RequireJS main method require which uses JavaScript callback trace to find event for loading main extension file and binds executes it with extension context.
https://github.com/salsita/browser-require/blob/master/require.js

It seems to work, but this solution has a few cons:

- bug reports are reported in "line 1, column 1" because this solution injects code directly to `func.call` - debugging is very hard
- Loaded JS files does not appear in console / chromebug
- If current tab uses HTTPS Chrome will disallow evaling scripts, especially this from local context (`file:///`), so it sometimes just dont work as expected

Comment: You're right, this is a really good extension. More or less a good implementation of the AJAX method. Of course, you can allow unsafe evaling of scripts but you know that doing that would be kind of a breach of trust for any users that download your extension. Best of luck.

Comment: Just wondering, with the first issue, can't you just press F11 in Chrome developer tools to step into the next function call?

Answer (score 49):

**UPDATE : This solution works only if you are using manifest V2.**

You can also do this the extremely easy way that is described here:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages#manifest

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "lib/fileone.js",
      "lib/filetwo.js",
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

You won't be doing lazy loading, but it does allow you to break your code up into multiple files and specify the order in which they are loaded onto the background page.

Comment: I can see what you're trying to say with your answer, but it's hard to understand (what exactly are you referring to in that page?). A tiny code snippet would improve your answer a lot. As is, this answer is "link-only" and may be deleted.

Comment: @Omn what are the pros and cons of your method versus the way that rsanchez suggests above?

Comment: **Beware:** the files order in ```scripts``` matters!

Comment: @Kamafeather Which is why the answer says that this allows you to "specify the order in which [the files] are loaded onto the background page."

Answer (score 16):

If you want to load a javascript file in the context of your background page and want to avoid using `eval`, you can just add a `script` tag to your background page's DOM. For instance, this works if your files are present in the `lib` folder of your extension:

```
function loadScript(scriptName, callback) {
    var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
    scriptEl.src = chrome.extension.getURL('lib/' + scriptName + '.js');
    scriptEl.addEventListener('load', callback, false);
    document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);
}
```

Comment: So you specify a background page instead of script and then add scripts to that page?

Comment: @mdenton8 You include this function in your background page script. Then you can call it to run scripts in that page.

Comment: @rsanchez is this answer out of date? Would you now recommend doing it the way Omn suggested below in his answer from 2015? Or are there pros and cons to both methods?

Comment: I can confirm that this solution worked for me and is still valid.

Answer (score 5):

**[manifest v3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/)** has changed a lot

[developer.chrome.com : Extension service worker basics](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/basics/#import-scripts)

[mdn : importScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts)

TL;DR

```
importScripts('script-1.js','script-2.js');
```

or more fully

```
  var err;
  try{      
        importScripts('nmhost/ext-nmhost.js');            
  }
  catch(err2){
        err    = err2;
  }
  if(err){    //handle error        
        console.error(err);            
  }
```

I have a useful example browser extension which makes use of `importScripts`, the extension allows launching elevated and non-elevated programs from the browser using the native messaging protocol, see [github : simple-nativemessaging - example directory](https://github.com/javascript-2020/simple-nativemessage)

further reading on this topic

[chrome developers : Improve extension security](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/improve-security/)

[chrome developers : Migrate to a service worker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/to-service-workers/)

for those who wish to develop using the old manifest v2, previous versions of chromium can be downloaded from [chromium.org : Downloading old builds of Chrome / Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/#downloading-old-builds-of-chrome-chromium), manifest V3 is supported generally in Chrome 88 ( January 19th, 2021 ) or later.

Comment: Works great and extremely simple, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could attempt to use web workers, perhaps. In your background.js, include:

```
var worker = new Worker('new-script.js');
```

Web workers can spawn new workers, and even have an importScript("new-script.js") method.

Web workers can tend to be very limited, however. Check [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) for a great article on Web workers.

I don't know if they would work, however. The other option is using XMLHTTPRequest (AJAX) to dynamically retrieve the script, and eval it. Over a non-HTTPS connection however, this is probably blocked due to man-in-the-middle attacks.
Alternatively, you can force Chrome to eval script from a non-encrypted connection (BUT DON'T DO IT) by adding this to `manifest.json`:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": ["http://badpractic.es/insecure.js"]
```

See [Load remote webpage in background page: Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845118/load-remote-webpage-in-background-page-chrome-extension) for a more in-depth discussion of the AJAX method.

So your options seem to be limited.

This of course loads them all at once:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js","background2.js","background3.js"] //and so on
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize you wanted lazy loading. I'll go looking, sorry

Comment: Allright, but I want to prevent loading all files at once. My extension sometimes doesnt use all of methods, so i want to load only what's currently necessary. In FireFox i've got `use` method (eg. `storage = myExtension.use('storage')` which loads `/lib/storage.js`) and want to create similar solution in Chrome/Safari :)

Comment: I gave you some more suggestions. Check my answer again? -Matt

Comment: Workers are some kind of solution, but their limitations disqualify them in my case - and also I would have to rewrite almost all code to use it as a worker services. But i've upvoted your answer, cuz if somebody is looking for this answer before writing any code it will be helpful.

Comment: I appreciate the upvote. Perhaps the AJAX method would be more helpful to you? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

What I've done isn't lazy loading but I load some files before the others when my chrome extension icon is clicked.  In my case, I wanted my util files before the others that utilize them:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/utils/utilFunction1.js"});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/utils/utilFunction2.js"});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/main.js"});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/otherFeature.js"});
});
```