# add external css and JS to backgroung script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to use some external CSS and JS to my chrome extenstion from the backgroung script, Suppose I want using the following files:

```
css/pnotify.css
js/pnotify.js
```

inside backgroung script I want to be able to write:

```
new PNotify({
   delay: 3000,
   title: 'Error',
   text: 'server not responding',
   type: 'error',
   styling: 'bootstrap3'
});
```

but when I'm getting error:

> PNotify is not defined

I tried to add in manifest like:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "css": [
        "css/pnotify.css"
    ],
    "js": [
        "js/pnotify.js"
    ]
}]
```

but still same error

Comment: Content script run in web pages. The background script runs in a hidden background page so your PNotify is meaningless there. Either do everything in the content script or don't use PNotify at all, use `chrome.notifications` API instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already a lot of subject about your problem, amoung them this seems to answer your question => [Multiple JS files in Chrome Extension - how to load them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651620/multiple-js-files-in-chrome-extension-how-to-load-them/18666353)