# Hooking document.write function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a Chrome extension that requires me to intercept the document.write function (Note: I am using content script). I'm using the method here: http://sitr.us/2012/09/04/monkey-patching-document-write.html
But it's not working correctly. This is what I have right now:

```
(function() {
    var originalWrite = document.write;
    alert("checkpoint 1");
    document.write = function() {
        alert("checkpoint 2");

        //secret stuff here         

        return Function.prototype.apply.call(
                        originalWrite, document, arguments);    
    }
})();
```

However, the "checkpoint 2" alert inside my hook never gets called when I call document.write on a web page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure about the workflow of extension ... but did you try `return originalWrite.apply(this, arguments);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your extension runs in its own sandbox, and [has no access to the web page's JavaScript environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285886/chrome-extension-adding-external-javascript-to-current-pages-html#answer-10371025). Overwriting `document.write` in your extension does not affect the `document.write` function of the web page itself.

Here's a quote from [the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/content_scripts.html):

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)
> - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> - **Use variables or functions defined by web pages** or by other content scripts

---

To alter the `document.write` function of the webpage, you'll have to [insert your script into the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879).

Comment: I'm using content script... so my script is inserted into the DOM

Comment: @EricChen - Wrong. Content scripts [are *not* inserted into the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285886/chrome-extension-adding-external-javascript-to-current-pages-html#answer-10371025).