# Metrics for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, metrics

I'm writing a chrome extension. This is my first time writing a chrome extension so apologies for asking a very basic question.

I'd like to know how I can measure the user activity on my extension. Can I use Google analytics for this? What technologies do people usually use to measure business metrics on Google chrome extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Indeed, if you had searched the documentation for "analytics", you would've found this:

[Tutorial: Google Analytics](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics)

Apparently, this is a bit outdated, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135000/how-do-you-integrate-universal-analytics-in-to-chrome-extensions) will help you.

*Morale: search first. Search docs, search Google, search Stack Overflow.*