# Enable analytics in chrome extension when internet is not available at start of extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I use analytics in my chrome extension like this

background.js

```
// Standard Google Universal Analytics code
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)    
{i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new     
Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)   
[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-  
analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); 

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-YY', 'auto');
ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', function(){}); // Removes failing protocol 
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
```

with all the necessary permissions in manifest.json

Everything works as expected , except the cases where there is not internet at the start of the extension. In cases like these,the events are not sent to server as analytics.js is not loaded. This leads to loss of events until the next chrome restart with successful internet connection.

Is there a workaround to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an elegant way of doing this

```
function loadAnalyticsScript() {
  // The standard Google Universal Analytics code
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); // Note: https protocol here
}

var analyticsLoaded = false;  // initialise

loadAnalyticsScript();


/************Detect if analytics script has loaded **********/

// Method 1 src:https://davidsimpson.me/2014/05/27/add-googles-universal-analytics-tracking-chrome-extension/#comment-190946

ga(function(){
  // This function will be triggered when GA is successfully loaded for the first time.
  console.log(' +++ Google Analytics has loaded');
  analyticsLoaded = true;
});

// Alternative Method 2 src:https://www.domsammut.com/code/workaround-for-when-the-hitcallback-function-does-not-receive-a-response-analytics-js
if (ga.hasOwnProperty('loaded') && ga.loaded === true) {

    console.log(' +++ Google Analytics has loaded');
    analyticsLoaded = true;

}

/*************************************************/

// All the events tracking goes here
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-YY', 'auto');
ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', function(){}); // Removes failing protocol check. @see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22152353/1958200
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview', '/options.html');

// Test to see if it's loaded yet.
var gaLoadTimer = setInterval(function(){

    if (analyticsLoaded === false) {
        console.log("Retrying for GA script");
        loadAnalyticsScript(); //try again
    }
    else{
        clearInterval(gaLoadTimer);
    }
}, 20000); // every 20s
```

Comment: Beware of using a 20s `setInterval`, it will fail if you use an Event page (`"persistent": false`)

Answer (score 2):

Use `XMLHttpRequest` to test whether `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js` is reachable. In case it's not, create a timer using [chrome.alarms API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) (preferably) or `setInterval` which would repeat this test. Once the site is reachable, initialize GA.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Also found an alternate to check whether analytics.js is loaded https://www.domsammut.com/code/workaround-for-when-the-hitcallback-function-does-not-receive-a-response-analytics-js

Comment: @mallik1055, that other method is worth being present here as answer with a link to the source article. Would you care to add it and maybe even select as the solution?