# Google Analytics Events for Chrome Browser Extension Not Firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I am trying to get Google Analytics events to fire from a chrome browser extension. I have the following code in my content script to inject ga:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://ssl.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', 'myTracker');

ga('myTracker.send', 'event', 'test_category', 'test_action', 'test_label');
```

In my manifest.json, I added the following line:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
```

The event does not seem to be triggering as it does not show up in my Google Analytics console. Does anybody know where I could be going wrong?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Put that code in a [sandboxed page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandbox) inside iframe in your background page.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion. However, I think sending the GA event from the background page would mean losing information in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines after 'create' command:

```
// will disable checks for http(s) protocol
ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', function(){}); 

// set your page here, helps to avoid rejection because of chrome-extension protocol
ga('send', 'pageview', '/popup.html');
```

You can find more in this discussion: [How do you integrate Universal Analytics in to Chrome Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135000/how-do-you-integrate-universal-analytics-in-to-chrome-extensions/22152353)