# What does this function do in the Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I am looking at how a Google extension ([SAML Chrome Panel](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/saml-chrome-panel/paijfdbeoenhembfhkhllainmocckace)) is constructed. The source code for this extension is [here](https://github.com/milton-lai/saml-chrome-panel) on GitHub.

My question is about a function in the **panel.js** script, located [here](https://github.com/milton-lai/saml-chrome-panel/blob/master/unpacked/panel/assets/javascripts/panel.js).

The panel.js script has the code shown below on lines 33-37. The function in question is the anonymous one that takes the parameters function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m).

```
SAMLChrome.controller('PanelController', function PanelController($scope, $http, toolbar) {
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://ssl.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

I can gather that the anonymous function loads the **analytics.js** file from a Google server. But besides that, does it embed an event listener into the elements that it finds using getElementsByTagName(), or what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the *analytics.js* library of Google Analytics. It is a JavaScript library for measuring users interaction.

In the **panel.js** file, below the code you entered there is the part  that send info to Google Analytics:

```
ga('create', 'UA-67121118-1', 'auto');
ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', function(){}); // Removes failing protocol check. @see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22152353/1958200
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview', '/panel.html');
```

You can find more info about this code here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/