# Google Chrome - Extension vs App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to modify chrome start page, change background and maybe logo.

I want to include jQuery in users local storage and load it while users page loads ( search page )

I never done anything with chrome so I want some way where to start. Do I go reading with apps or extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb: Choose an [app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) if you want to develop an (independent) application that can stand on its own. If you want to interact with the browser (e.g. modify a web page), build [an extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/).

In your case, you definitely need an extension.

- Change start page - use [`chrome_url_overrides`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html) in the manifest file to override `newtab`.
- Locally store jQuery: Although it's possible to store jQuery in local storage, you're probably fine with packaging jQuery with your extension.
  To add it to your user's "search page", you have to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). By default, content scripts run in an execution environment that is different from the page (the document's DOM is shared though). Usually, this behavior is desired. If you really want to expose the jQuery library to the scripts in the page, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879).
  If you really want to load some script from a remote location and use it as a content script, read [Chrome extension adding external javascript to current page's html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285886/chrome-extension-adding-external-javascript-to-current-pages-html/10371025#10371025).

I'm not sure what you mean by "change background and maybe logo". If you're referring to the browser's appearance, the only option to do that is by creating a [theme](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes.html). This **must** be a separate extension.

Comment: thanks you, this preatty much covers everything I wanted to know.
Just for information, by "change background and maybe logo too" I ment `newtab` background and google logo - in new chrome newtab the default tab is google search - and google logo is what I mean

Comment: The "override page" feature allows you to do that.