# Are Chrome Extensions supported on mobile?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Do Chrome extensions work well on mobile phones?

I want to create an extension but unsure whether it will work on mobile devices.

If not, do I have to use a service like PhoneGap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome does not support extensions on mobile devices.

[Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), however, are another story. There is a toolchain, [`cca` or Chrome Apps for Mobile](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps), based on Apache Cordova that can compile an app into a native Android/iOS app.

Make sure you understand the [differences between extensions and apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459309/google-chrome-extension-vs-app).

> As a rule of thumb: Choose an app if you want to develop an (independent) application that can stand on its own. If you want to interact with the browser (e.g. modify a web page), build an extension.

Also take note of [API limitations](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/docs/APIsAndLibraries.md) of `cca`-translated Apps.