# Cant run Chrome Extension because "it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I get the error

Refused to frame 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/js/xdrpc.html?v=0.0.2000-RC8.42627-1422#xdm_e=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com&xdm_c=default5058&xdm_p=1#mode=cors' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src

when I try to run the Rapportive chrome extension using my personal gmail address but don't get that error in Chrome when logged in under a different (company) account and email address in gmail.

Any suggestion on what to change in the browser settings or something?

I tried creating a new user in chrome and reloading the Rapportive chrome extension but that didn't work either. I removed and reinstalled from www.rapportive.com under my company email address and that still works.

Comment: Possibly duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641592/injecting-iframe-into-page-with-restrictive-content-security-policy

Comment: Not sure how I did it but eventually I realized by looking at the networking tab of dev tools that the auth token had expired and then there was an iframe button to authorize my linkedin account so it is working now. I am not sure why the auth token expired and if there was a connection to my looking at the networking traffic that triggered it to request to re-authorize.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why/how I was able to get the rapportive chrome extension to show a button to re-authenticate but it did and it seems to be working now. Thanks!

Comment: Ans pls mark it as the answer so it doesn't pop up as an unanswered question anymore :)