# WebExtensions API - create a "popup" with no title bar title and buttons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, modal-dialog, popup, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to know if there is a way to create the same kind of a popup window that you can get with the API for toolbar button or address bar button described here: [Popups API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Popups) Either achieved true the WebExtensions API or other means.

More specifically I do not need the window title bar or title bar buttons nor the address bar, forward/backward buttons etc. Like shown here:

[image: Pop up example picture]

According to the documentation you can create extension pages, but they do include title bar and title bar buttons - [Extension pages API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Extension_pages)
Like this one: [image]

**Purpose:** I have created my self an extension which adds a button to the contents of a specific web site. When the button is pressed it opens a new tab with a certain cross origin web page. I do not want to click around closing the opened new tab to go back to the previous. A pop up page here will make my life a bit easier as whenever you click outside of it - it closes.

**What I tried:** Tried opening the external web page as a modal `<iframe>`. But this leads to a CSP violation in the rare cases that I need to interact with it.

*The used images are from the MDB web docs*

Comment: Extensions can't do that. Extensions can add a frame element into the web page and make it look like that. See also [Injecting iframe into page with restrictive Content Security Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24649134)

Comment: @wOxxOm this is a lifesaver. Thanks for providing that answer in the comments. If you submit it as an answer I will be very happy to accept it.