# WebExtensions API - inject modal to website with <iframe> content and pass cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, iframe, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am using *(fraction of)* the accepted answer in: [Inject iframe into page with restrictive content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641592/injecting-iframe-into-page-with-restrictive-content-security-policy/24649134#24649134) to inject `<iframe>` to a webpage that is part of the content of a modal window. Currently I am able to access the external website displayed in the `<iframe>` and pass my cookies to it just fine, but upon interacting with it *(clicking on a submit button)* my cookies are not sent with the `onclick` event (which points to a JS function making AJAX request to the server). Therefor the server says that I am not logged in.

**The question:** How to pass the cookies with the AJAX? Is that even possible?

**What I have tried:** Editing the cookies `SameSite` value to `None` and the `Secure` to `true` for the website displayed in the `<iframe>` allows the cookies to be passed. It is desirable however not instruct the user to modify browser settings or cookies.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Add button",
  "description": "This extension will add some buttons to page.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "webNavigation",
   "tabs",
   "https://*.example.com/*",
   "https://external-iframe-site.com/*"
   ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "contentBackground.js",
    "modal.js",
    "iframe.html"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
const filter = {
    url: [
        {
            urlMatches: '(example.com\/in)'
        }
    ]
}

chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(
    function(details) 
    {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"jquery-1.6.1.min.js"},
            function()
            {
                chrome.tabs.insertCSS({file: "content.css"});
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"modal.js"});
            });
    }, filter);
```

**iframe.html**

```
<iframe src="https://external-iframe-site.com/php/sync_user.php?action=Check&profileCode=someProfileCodeForTheExample" 
></iframe>
```

**modal.js**

```
let a = document.createElement("a");  // Create Check with DOM
    a.innerHTML = "Check";
    a.id = "chkBtn";
    a.target = "_blank";
    let checkLink = "https://external-iframe-site.com/php/sync_user.php?action=Check&profileCode={profileCode}";
    checkLink = checkLink.replace("{profileCode}", encodeURI(window.location.href));
    a.href = checkLink;
    $("div.target").prepend(a);

var modal = (function(){
    var 
    method = {},
    $overlay,
    $modal,
    $content,
    $close;

// ... methods for closing/opening/etc. that you do not need to know ...

    // Generate the HTML and add it to the document
    $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    $modal = $('<div id="modal"></div>');
    $content = $('<div id="content"></div>');
    $close = $('<a id="close" href="#">close</a>');

    $modal.hide();
    $overlay.hide();
    $modal.append($content, $close);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.authentication-outlet').append($overlay, $modal);
    });

    return method;
}());

// Get iframe local url
var iframeOrigin = chrome.runtime.getURL('iframe.html');

// Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chkBtn').click(function(e){
        //Opens the modal with "src" of the local iframe.html file
        modal.open({content:
       '<iframe src=' + '"' + iframeOrigin + '"'+' width="992" height="500"></iframe>'
    });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: You can set `document.cookie` in the content script that runs on that site. The content script should be declared with `"all_frames": true`. Alternatively you can add the `cookie` header via chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.

Comment: @wOxxOm I thought about that, but as far as I know I can not grab site specific cookies? Or I am wrong? Shouldn't I set the `document.cookie` in the `iframe.html` file?

Comment: In the content script that runs on that site (in the iframe).

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry maybe there is misunderstanding. I will try to explain the structure in couple of words. We have the website that you visit lets say, youtube, there I will be appending a button (with the help of the background,js). When pressed this button will open a modal window with it's contents being the iframe.html file I have locally which on the other hand has a `<iframe>` with the external website that we are trying to mingle with.

Comment: Yes, my idea is that you declare a content script that will run inside that iframed site. It will receive the cookies via extension messaging and set them via `document.cookie` as session cookies. An entirely different approach would be to use `chrome.cookies` API.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think I got it now. Would you provide me a code sample how to send a message from the iframed site, please?

Comment: @wOxxOm I have created a content script that runs inside that framed site. It sets some cookies with `document.cookie` and after that `console.log(document.cookie)`, unfortunately it log an empty string. I must be missing something here.