# Fire Keydown event in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, keydown

I'm doing a Google Chrome extension that interacts with Gmail chat and can send the same message to all open chat, the functional part is done, but I can not send the `keydown` event to the textareas.

What I am doing is using a `page_action` to show the extension icon when the user visit Gmail. When the user click the extension icon, it is going to prompt a popup with a textarea, when the user have opened chat and write something to the textarea and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the textarea of each opened chat are going to fill the same message and suppused to fire `keydown` event.

Here is the essential code:

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'send.js'}, function () {
  // 'message' is the textarea inside the popup.html
  var message = document.getElementById('message');

  message.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (13 == e.keyCode) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: 'send("' + message.value + '");'}, function () {
        message.value = '';
      });
      return false;
    }
  };
});
```

**send.js**

```
function send(message) {
  if (message) {
    for (var i = 0, textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA"), length = textareas.length; i < length; ++i) {
      textarea = textareas[i];
      textarea.value = message;

      var evt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');

      evt.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 13, 13);

      Object.defineProperty(evt, 'keyCode', {
        get : function() {
            return 13;
        }
      });

      Object.defineProperty(evt, 'which', {
        get : function() {
            return 13;
        }
      });

      Object.defineProperty(evt, 'keyIdentifier', {
        get : function() {
            return 'Enter';
        }
      });

      Object.defineProperty(evt, 'shiftKey', {
        get : function() {
            return false;
        }
      });

      textarea.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
  }
}
```

The code did not have problem filling the textareas, so all textareas is reconized, but the `keydown` event did not fire after the script filled textareas. The strange part, is when I tried the *send.js* code into the Google Chrome console, the `keydown` event fire normally and the messages were send, but I can't do samething with the extension.

So, how can I fire the `keydown` event into the extension?

Comment: can you provide js fiddle demo

Comment: Had you used the Chrome Inspector in the extension or just in the web page?

Comment: @NathanCampos I used Developer Tools to inspect the popup and the web page.

Comment: @shareef I think I can't, because this is a Google Chrome extension for Gmail, so it need the user visit the Gmail page first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail is composed of frames.
By default, [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) only injects code in the main (top-window) frame. To also inject the code in the subframes, add `allFrames: true` to your details.

Also, do **NOT** use `'send("' + USER_INPUT_HERE + '");'` to trigger your function. This makes your application **vulnerable to script injections.** Use [`JSON.stringify(USER_INPUT_HERE)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to correctly escape the string.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: 'send.js',
    allFrames: true
}, function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: 'send(' + JSON.stringify(message.value) + ');',
        allFrames: true
    });
    message.value = '';
});
```

<sub>Example of the vulnerability:

User input: `" + (function(){while(1)chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://evil.com"})}()) + "`</sub>

---

Objects created by the extension are never passed to a page. Properties and property descriptors added to an event are lost when passed to the page. Instead of a content script, I advise to use an [injected script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) <sup>[What is the difference between an injected script, Content script and extension code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916089/938089?chrome-extension-auto-run-a-function)</sup> to get the desired effect:

```
// Script to be injected
var code = '(' + function(message) {
    /* .. "function send"'s body from send.js .. */
} + ')(' + JSON.stringify(message.value) + ');';
// Content script which *injects* the script
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: 'var s = document.createElement("script");' +
          's.textContent = ' + JSON.stringify(code) + ';' + 
          '(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);' + 
          's.parentNode.removeChild(s);' /*<--Clean-up*/
});
```

For clarification, the previous snippet results in the following code to be [**injected**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) in the page:

```
(function(message) { /* logic of send */ })("user input");
```

The Event object is constructed and passed within Gmail's page, so that all properties are preserved, as if you used the console to execute the script. **It does not run in the context of your extension any more**.

Comment: Thank you for point out the vulnerability. I know that Gmail is composed of frames, but the chat in Gmail is outside the frame so that is not the problem. I don't have problem with modify the value of textareas, so the problem is not that the script cannot found the textarea, the problem is that the script don't fire `keydown` event correctly.

Comment: @Fong-WanChau Edited answer to target yet *another* problem.

Comment: But the Object is created inside the `send.js` that are injected to the page, so technically the Object are created inside the page. I used `console.log(evt)` and in the page inspector I can see the `evt` are created correctly.

Comment: @Fong-WanChau I recommend to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9916089/938089?chrome-extension-auto-run-a-function).

Comment: Already read your answer on other post, and tried your methods, but it did not work.

Comment: Ok, I made a test locally, and found that `KeyboardEvent` has been fired with `keyCode: 0`, this is the caused by a [old not fixed bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16735).. The `Object.defineProperty` method did not work in this case (I don't know why), so, that is the problem and I just need to wait until the patch is released.

Comment: @Fong-WanChau Properly implemented, it *has to* work, because you said "when I tried the send.js code into the Google Chrome console, the keydown event fire normally and the messages were send". But, I did not implement it correctly, it was still a content script :p Updated answer (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) for other methods to **inject** a script using a Chrome extension).

Comment: +1 Wow, it's working now! The problem seem to be caused by inject script directly. (As if we use `executeScript` method, we never can access defined variable in the web...). Thank you!