# Chrome: Uncaught ReferenceError jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension. It takes the username's background picture url and puts it to the page. But it gives unexpected error. The error text is:

> The page at https://twitter.com/jack ran insecure content from
>   http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=jack&callback=jQuery18207089675806928426_1351333462593&_=1351333462594.
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery18207089675806928426_1351333462593 is
>   not defined (anonymous function)

[image: error message]

The extension folder contains these files:

> action.js // 
>   background.html // 
>   jquery.min.js // 
>   manifest.json

[image: folder]

action.js:

```
var userPage = document.URL;

var arr = userPage.split("/");
var username = "";
for(i=3;i<4;i++)
    username += arr[i];

var page = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name="+username+"&callback=?"; 

background();

function background() {
        $.getJSON(page, function(data) {
            $("span.screen-name").append(" • <a href='"+data.profile_background_image_url+"'>B</a> • ");
        });     
}
```

background.html:

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javas.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

jquery.min.js is taken from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Twitter Background",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "description": "Puts the background image url to the profile page.",
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://twitter.com/*","https://twitter.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js","action.js"],
      "all_frames":true

    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error ("The page at https:... ran insecure content from http://...") is just a warning, and non-critical.

The second error is caused by the difference in execution context. See [Chrome extension code vs Content scripts vs Injected scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915311/chrome-extension-code-vs-content-scripts-vs-injected-scripts). As you can see by looking at the first warning, a JSONP request is made. This means that a `<script>` element is injected in the page. This script calls a function (`jQuery182....`), which cannot be found, because jQuery was loaded in the context of a content script.

To solve the problem, either [inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879) `action.js` in the page, or (recommended) add `https://api.twitter.com/*` to the permissions section of your manifest file, and don't use `?callback=?` in the URL you're passing to `$.getJSON`.