# chrome.tabs.create - callback function never called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a new tab using Chrome Extension and when tab is loaded to show `tab.id`. Page is loaded but callback function is not worked (alert with `tab.id` is now showed).

The *background.js* file:

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'http://www.google.com'}, function(tab){ alert(tab.id) })
```

The *manifest.json* file:

```
 {
     "name": "Test",
     "version": "1.0",
     "description": "Test plugin",
     "browser_action": {
         "default_popup": "popup.html",
         "default_icon":"icon.png"
     },
     "background": {
         "scripts": ["background.js"]
     },
     "manifest_version":2,
     "permissions": [
          "tabs",
          "http://*.facebook.com/*",
          "http://*.google.com/*",
          "storage"
     ]
}
```

The *popup.html* file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test tabs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=/background.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What can be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code must be located in [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

This is in the *manifest.json* file:

```
"background" : {"scripts" : ["background_script.js"] }
```

or

```
"background" : {"page" : "background_page.html" }
```

You need to use absolute path when you referring to the file inside background page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/background.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions/errors while you run your extension?

Comment: There are no exceptions appeared on extensions page

Comment: maybe something wrong with my popup.html? added it now

Comment: background.js should be loaded from background.html or something like that?

Comment: Still does not work.. Something is still missing. Did you tried with exact those 3 files? Sorry to bother you again and thank for your help

Comment: Yes, I tried with those files and works fine. Do you have latest version of the Google Chrome?

Comment: Tried it again and it works now with html fix:) Did not paid attention that script is running only once on browser load

Answer (score 0):

I think callback function is executed in another context, and alert will not work.
Try to open background page and DevTools and use console.log(tab.id) for see tab ID.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the "another context"? There are some restrictions of what callback function can do?

Comment: @shtkuh Chrome extensions scripts has 3 context of executing:
 -background scripts (wxecuting into extension)<br/>
 -content scripts ( can read and modify the DOM for the displayed web page) <br/> - injected scripts <br/>More info on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915311/chrome-extension-code-vs-content-scripts-vs-injected-scripts)

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution:
`chrome.tabs.create({url: URL, selected: false}, function(tab) { alert(tab.id) })`

Not sure whether this is what you expected but the alert would work!