# Pass parameter in javascript function inside chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm bulilding a chrome extension.
In this part of code I try to find paragraphs in loaded page, for each paragraph in divs with id load and detail, I search if value of `findCheckedFact` is inside that paragraph if yes I cut I want to put that text inside a span with a class red.

`findCheckedFact` is a string. Here in   `+'console.log("Print:", str_p, " Fact:", findCheckedFact);'` the text inside paragraph is defined but the parameter findCheckedFact is not defined, so I cant pass it? 
This function I tried calling `findTextInsideParagraphs("test");`.

```
function findTextInsideParagraphs(findCheckedFact){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"}, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({"code":
                '(function(findCheckedFact){'
                    +'$("#lead, #detail").find("p").each(function() {'
                            +'var str_p = $(this).text();'
                            +'console.log("Print:", str_p, " Fact:", findCheckedFact);'
                            +'if (str_p.indexOf( findCheckedFact) >= 0) {'
                                +'console.log("Yes kest");'
                                +'$(this).html($(this).html().replace(findCheckedFact, "<span class=\'red\'> $& </span>"));'
                            +'}'
                    +'});'
                 +'}(' + JSON.stringify("Fact: " , findCheckedFact) + '));'
             });
        });

}
```

This function I tried calling findTextInsideParagraphs("test");
Inside manifest.json I did add everythin possible to make it work:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "custom-css.css"
      ],
       "js": [
        "js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": [
      "js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js",
      "background.js",
      "popup.js",
      "blic-fact-checker.js"
    ],
    "css":["custom-css.css"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "background",
    "notifications",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://localhost:5000/*",
    "chrome-extension://genmdmadineagnhncmefadakpchajbkj/blic-fact-checker.js",
    "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?&remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@202161/&dockSide=undocked",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
```

Can somebody help me with this,really I can't find what's going on ?

Answer (score 1):

First, read [this explanation of different kinds of javascript code in Chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915311/chrome-extension-code-vs-content-scripts-vs-injected-scripts)

As you see, your code in `executeScript` is a content script, and it has no direct access to the code in background and other proper extension pages. You have 3 main options:

1) send your `FindCheckedFact` to the content script with `sendMessage` or `port.postMessage`. Of course, in your content script you have to establish listeners for them, and put the actual code in these listeners.

2) save your variable in local or sync storage, putting your `executeScript` in the callback, and read them from your content script. If you need to re-read it sometimes, set a listener for storage change in the content script.

These solutions work both with a content script in a .js file, and an inline content script. But, since you choose inlining, and you have only to send a value one way, you can

3) just stringify your `FindCheckedFact` (with JSON.stringify or toString), and insert its value with +:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({"code":
            '(function('+strFindCheckedFact+'){'
```

etc.