# Can Tampermonkey Userscript access Chrome API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am developing a userscript that requiers `chrome` object, but I can't access it. How to access to `chrome` object inside tampermonkey's userscript? Maybe, some permissions in manifest or what...

Comment: You can only access the web-exposed `unsafeWindow.chrome` object but *only if it's defined for that page, which is not guaranteed*. It has just a few basic methods like chrome.runtime.sendMessage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to [Chrome extension code vs Content scripts vs Injected scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915311/chrome-extension-code-vs-content-scripts-vs-injected-scripts).

Chrome extensions can access [Chrome APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) and Tampermonkey *is* an extension.
However, Tampermonkey must make a given API's functionality to a userscript via `GM_` functions.

If there is not a `GM_` function for what you want, then you must find another way or write a Chrome extension instead of a Tampermonkey script.